# Static Object in C++

Tags: c++, object

I have `Mtx` that does some calculations between matrices

```
Mtx M1(rows1,cols1,1); //instantiate data members and fill the matrix with 1s
Mtx M2(rows2,cols2,2); //instantiate data members and fill the matrix with 2s

Mtx M3(rows3,cols3,0); //instantiate data members and fill the matrix with 0s


M3 += M1; //+= is overloaded - First M3
M3 -= M2; //-= is overloaded - Second M3
```

The first `M3` takes `M3` that filled with zeros and adds it to `M1` and the answer will be assign to `M3`. I have no problem here.

The problem is with the second `M3`! It doesn't subtract `M3` that filled with zeros, rather It  uses the result from the previous operation and subtracts it from `M2`.

How can I make `M3` static that keeps its values? Is it something related to static object?
I hope you got my point!

Your help is appreciated...

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't declare M2? Please show the code of the `operator+=()`

Comment: And... please tell us what you expect M1, M2 and M3 to be after the operations.

Comment: can you provide some more code?

Comment: @steffen `M3 = M3 + M1` ---> to a new value of M3. That new value will be used in `M3 = M3 - M1` which I don't that to be.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're using the **`+=` operator**. You're **assigning** *new values* to the object on the left.

When you use `+=` you are changing the value of M3.

What you want is this:

```
Mtx M4 = M3 + M1;
Mtx M5 = M3 - M2;
```

Or even better:

```
const static Mtx ZERO_MTX(rows3,cols3,0);
Mtx M4 = ZERO_MTX + M1;
Mtx M5 = ZERO_MTX - M2;
```